# jQuery extended function not initialized

Tags: jquery

Working in Firebug Console, but not from file.

Google Chrome - Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'listAttributes'

Firefox - $(".div4").listAttributes is not a function

```
<script src='/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.listAttributes.js'></script>

<div class='div4' style='color:red;'>
</div>

<script>
$(".div4").listAttributes();
 </script>
```

jquery.listAttributes.js:

```
if(jQuery) {
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery.fn.listAttributes = function(prefix) {
            var list = [];
            $(this).each(function() {
                console.info(this);
                var attributes = [];
                for(var key in this.attributes) {
                    if(!isNaN(key)) {
                        if(!prefix || this.attributes[key].name.substr(0,prefix.length) == prefix) {
                            attributes.push(this.attributes[key].name);
                        }
                    }
                }
                list.push(attributes);
            });
            return (list.length > 1 ? list : list[0]);
        }
    });
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code:

```
$(".div4").listAttributes();
```

Is running *before* `document.ready`, but your plugin isn't defined *until* `document.ready`, just remove the `jQuery(document).ready(function() { });` wrapper from your plugin :)

---

Another note, the call to the plugin *should* be in a `document.ready` handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(".div4").listAttributes();
});
```

This ensures that the `.div4` elements are in the DOM and ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `$(".div4").listAttributes();` inline in the script (so it is called when the browser parses that `<script>` element) but you are assigning `jQuery.fn.listAttributes` inside a `ready` event so it doesn't exist until after the browser has finished parsing the *entire* document.